# Google Sheets API: Update the range of all conditional formattings

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a nodejs app which uses the google sheets api to update and add new rows to a spreadsheet. Now I want to update the range of all conditional formattings if a new row was added. I know there is a [updateConditionalFormatRuleRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updateconditionalformatrulerequest) for batchUpdates, but I think I can't use it for that. The first problem is that I dont know how to get all conditional formattings of a sheet to update them. My only idea is to count them manually for each sheet and then make a for loop with this number. The second problem is that I dont know how to update just the end row of the range. Because I think I have to submit a full GridRange Object and not only the endRowIndex. And if I do it with the for loop, how should I know the column of the current conditional formatting. My other idea is to delete all conditional formattings and add them again with the new range. But then I have to code all existing conditional formattings now, and that are many. So is there a better way how I can make all conditional formattings over all rows, even if there will come a new row?

Answer (score 0):

To *make all conditional formattings over all rows, even if there will come a new row* apply whole column references. Instead of say `$A2:$A9` apply `$A:$A`.